# How to automate a flex application in Selenium WebDriver

Tags: flash, apache-flex, selenium, automation, selenium-webdriver

I want to automate a flex application using Selenium WebDriver. I searched a lot in internet and I found two things [**sfapi**](https://code.google.com/p/sfapi/) and [**FlexUISelenium**](https://code.google.com/p/flex-ui-selenium/). Both the projects are stopped in 2009 itself and further there is no development.

Both the project has more limitations and need to be run in Selenium RC. Actually I need any way or work around to automate a flex application in WebDriver.

**Update:**

Can any one please tell me how to install and work with Flex Monkey. I read the document in Gorilla Logic home page it said there should be no more Flex monkey. Is it true?

Please suggest me if any work around is available.

Answer (score 0):

Did you hear about Sikuli? Here is a couple of links http://code.google.com/p/sikuli-api/wiki/SikuliWebDriver  http://www.sikuli.org/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know about sikuli. It works based on Image recognition technique. But i need to interact the application as like selenium(without using saved image to interact). Please give me if any other work around is there?

Comment: You can integrate Sikuli with Selenium WebDriver